# How to analyze performance test results eliminating the influence of CPU frequency?

Tags: linux, performance, cpu, benchmarking

I have the nbench benchmark.

For each of the tests (sort, fourier, huffman, etc.) is the result of iterations/sec. The tests are run on each of the computers on one core. Processors have different frequencies (CPU2 > CPU1). I want to make the results "independent of CPU frequency".

Can I devide the results of more powerful PC by a factor of?
k = CPU2(more powerful)/CPU1.

Or should I do more complex calculations? What?

Comment: I want to compare the performance of optimizing compilers

Comment: I do not think that it makes much sense to try to eliminate a single factor. There are much more parameters which can, depending on the work to do, have more influence, for example the cache structure (L1/L2/L3), memory access times etc. If a calculation for example must access large parts of the memory, the speed will not linearly increase with the cpu frequency, even on otherwise identical CPUs. I would suggest to run the tests on _identical_ hardware to be meaningful, why is this not an option in your case?

Comment: @Ctx 
At my disposal processors of different architectures. I certainly understand that the test results influenced by other factors in addition to frequency. With this test I want to test the effectiveness of an optimizing compiler for CPU X (compared to gcc). Maybe I should look for another approach to solving my problem?